# How to keep routerLinkActive active on other pages?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
   <a *ngFor="let p of pages" routerLink="{{ p.path }}" routerLinkActive="page-selected" class="item">
{{ p.title }}</a>
```

I have a component that creates a tab bar (above) with a few pages and a class added to the respective active tab using routerLinkActive. I need certain tabs to stay highlighted when on specific other pages, which means the routerLink won't match and the routerLinkActive class won't be applied. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

For RouterLinkActive, it is necessary that the URL should be there to be active. But if you want to active the URL on some specific URL's then you may use [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"

Otherwise, please search about routerActive options from angular.io

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you 'within' one tab toogle between two views? Then you could create two components that you show and hide in the tab panel